# DockPanel Suite - DockContent visibility

Tags: c#, winforms, dockpanel-suite

A form contains a DockPanel with an instance of DockContent which has DockState=DockState.DockBottomAutoHide and it acts as a logger view - like Visual Studio's Error list panel. So, when a logging event is added to log list, DockPanel - if is not visible - is shown in next way:

```
{
  loggerList.AddLogEvent(event);
  loggerContentPanel.Show();
};
```

but if loggerContentPanel is already visible for user, Show method make the panel to "blink".
Is any way to get the state of a DockContent with DockState = DockState.DockBottomAutoHide if is visible for user? IsHidden or Visible properties doesn't help too much.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Alright... What I found is, when the panel is hidden, the property "IsActivated" is false, and is true when it's showing.

Comment: IsActivated is false when the dock is hidden. I admit, this lib would win to have some comments on those properties and methods.