# How to programmatically activate a AutoHide form?

Tags: c#, winforms, dockpanel-suite

I have a `DockContent` with `DockState = DockState.DockBottomAutoHide`.
How to make this window visible again?

With 'Visible' I mean not to change `DockState` to `DockState.DockBottom` but just to pop it up (slide out) - same behavior as when hover the mouse over the auto-hide tab.

I searched around for hours, without success.
Answer that don't work in my context: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843604/calling-up-dockpanel-suites-autohidden-dockcontent-programmatically/13844835#13844835)

Comment: What version are you using?  I would expect the solution discussed in the link you referenced to work (setting the ActiveAutoHideContent).

Comment: It's version 2.5. Set `ActiveAutoHideContent` to what?

Comment: 2.5 is quite out of date.  With this version, however, you should be able to call Show() on the DockContent you wish to "slide out." The link you provided explains the bug that broke that functionality in a later version, and provides the alternate method of setting ActiveAutoHideContent to that DockContent you wish to display.

Comment: @roken: Thanks, that worked. Please provide this as answer so I can upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.5 is quite out of date, so I would encourage you to upgrade to a more recent version of the 2.x series if at all possible.

With this version, however, you should be able to call `Show()` on the `DockContent` you wish to "slide out." The [link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843604/calling-up-dockpanel-suites-autohidden-dockcontent-programmatically/13844835#13844835) explains the [bug](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/80) that broke that functionality in a later version, and provides the alternate method of setting `ActiveAutoHideContent` to that `DockContent` you wish to display.