# DockPanelSuite's DockState and AutoHide

Tags: c#, winforms, dockpanel-suite

Working with DockState and AutoHide, I am looking for the following things:

1. Find out if the DockContent is in AutoHide mode
2. Ability to toggle between 'regular' and AutoHide mode.
3. Trigger an event when an AutoHide dock has come into view.
4. Trigger an event when an AutoHide dock has 'left' and is now docked back into it's tab.

Answer Wiki:

1. IsAutoHide - get:

   ```
   private WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState[] AutoHideStates = new WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState[] {
       WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState.DockBottomAutoHide,
       WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState.DockLeftAutoHide,
       WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState.DockRightAutoHide,
       WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState.DockTopAutoHide };

   public bool IsAutoHide { get { return AutoHideStates.Contains(DockContent.DockState); } }
   ```
2. IsAutoHide - set:
   No code yet - basically iterate through the modes or use a dictionary of interchangable modes (i.e. DockBottomAutoHide to DockBottom)
3. I have no idea, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956147/dockpanel-suite-dockcontent-visibility) looks interesting, might have the idea.
4. I have no idea.

Comment: I wonder what made this question downgraded, please comment.

Comment: Next time you might come to GitHub's issue tracker directly, https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues?state=open

Comment: I tried going there, but there doesn't seem to be a 'standard' forum there, only issue tracker, and I didn't want to open an issue till I was sure it was one. This place (SO) is a perfect knowledge sharing place.

Comment: You misunderstood the meaning of issues on GitHub. Take a look at the existing issues there, you can see that all kinds of discussions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is a decent way to accomplish this. The library has an internal method, `DockHelper.IsDockStateAutoHide()` that does basically the same thing.  This should actually be made into a public extension method and included as part of the library.

2 Your solution is good.

3 & 4 would probably be best implemented as a new event in the `DockPanel`: `ActiveAutoHideContentChanged`. You could then track the last autohide content on your own and when the event is raised you know that #3 is occurring if the new value is not null and #4 is occurring if the last known value was not null.

Feel free to open a request on [GitHub](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues) to have the event added.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried making your life a bit easier and (after a short learning curve) entered a [pull request](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/pull/81) to the github project.